# How do I get the value of my textbox in my actionlink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass the value of my `@HtmlTextBox("UserName")` to my get method in my controller from my view via my `@html.ActionLink`. Here is what I have tried:

```
@Html.TextBox("UserName")
@foreach (string s in ViewBag.RolesForThisUser)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @s
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Remove Role", "DeleteRoleForUser",
            new{controller = "Role",
            UserName=@Html.TextBox("UserName").ToString(), RoleName=@s})
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

Where this is out of scope it seems a bit tricky. This works well with the RoleName variable because it is within scope. Is there no way to get the value using the given variables?

**Resolution**
Taking a que from Scartag I came up with this

```
$(function () {
    $("#lnk")
        .click(function () {
            console.log("my message");
            var userName = $("#UserName").val();
            this.href = this.href + '&UserName=' + userName;
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is wrong.

Each time you see the `@Html.TextBox("UserName")` markup, you are telling the runtime to create an input field with id and name "Username"... that's all.

It doesn't translate into a value.

You could however use javascript to add an `onclick` to the `actionlink` which would append the value of the textbox before navigating to whatever url you want it to get to.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is checking on FormCollection which value you are posting

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult SubmitAction(FormCollection collection)
{
  // Get Post Params Here
  string var1 = collection["UserName"];
}
```

Check that you use the correct id name to retrieve the value